# Import data that is represented by grouped yearly columns

Tags: powerquery, m

I'm trying to import many sheets of data that into Powerquery that all look like this :

Simulation1:

| -- | -- | 2024 | 2024 | 2025 | 2025 | 2026 | 2026 | 20XX | 20YY | 2035 | 2035 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Month | Hour | D | A | D | A | D | A | D | A | D | A |
| Jan | 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| Jan | 6 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| Jan | ... | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| Jan | 23 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| Feb | 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| Feb | ... | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| Dec | 23 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |

Simulation 2:
same format etc.

**How can i import it through powerquery so that it looks like this :**

| Month | Hour | Year | Direction | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 5 | 2024 | D | 1 |
| Jan | 5 | 2026 | D | 5 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| Mar | 7 | 2028 | A | .. |
| Dec | 23 | 2026 | A | 6 |

anything involving depivoting doesn't seem to work as i can't get the Year values quite embeded with the data. also tried transforming into lists and rebuilding but i'm not that profficient in powerquery either.

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

It processes all files and sheets in a directory, then transforms as requested

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\temp"),  
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),  
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),   
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),    
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}), 
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data2", each 
    let #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip([Data],1),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Top Rows", {"Column1", "Column2"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    z = {List.Repeat(List.RemoveFirstN(Record.FieldValues([Data]{0}),2),Table.RowCount([Data])-1)},
    combined = Table.FromColumns(z&Table.ToColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"))
    in combined),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Added Custom1"[Data2], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),  
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Data2", List,List),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Data",{"Data"})    
in  #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

Rename as needed

Comment: thanks, it's a great start. it doesn't quite work because my real data was very slightly more complex. Could you help me understand the custom column ? let #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip([Data],1),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Top Rows", {"Column1", "Column2"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    z = {List.Repeat(List.RemoveFirstN(Record.FieldValues([Data]{0}),2),Table.RowCount([Data])-1)},
    combined = Table.FromColumns(z&Table.ToColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"))
    in combined),

Comment: break it into pieces and step through it with a single data source and you can see what it does